# How to detect a player being killed by a certain mob

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How to I detect a player getting killed by a zombie but not a skeleton?

I know I have to use scoreboards, but I only found deathCount.
Or I can test for a mob that killed a player, but I don’t know how to do that

Comment: I believe the criteria is stat.entityKilledBy.Zombie

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer by TQ1000
"I believe the criteria is stat.entityKilledBy.Zombie"